# Asp.net custom validator control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This is my issue:
We use custom validators for some fields. And now we want to change validation markup. For now this is something like that:
`<span id="CreateProfile_EmailValidator">Email is in Incorrect Format</span>`.

Can I somehow change this markup?
For example add some `<div>` elements?

UPD: I looked not for onetime workaround. (Please see discussion of the MikeSmithDev's answer)

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You can apply a class (`CssClass`) to the validator. Also, RegularExpressionValidator is good for email.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I now about `CssClass`, but I need instead `<span>` use `div` and other html elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit from `BaseValidator` or `CustomValidator` class and override `Render` method, and then generate whatever markup you want.

```
public class MyCustomValidator : CustomValidator
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag("div");
        base.Render(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [WebControlAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adapters.webcontroladapter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to change the way of how `CustomValidator` is rendered. You will want to override `RenderBeginTag` and `RenderEndTag` methods to render your div around the default span.

```
public class CustomValidatorAdapter : WebControlAdapter
{
    protected override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag("div");
                base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
    }

    protected override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
                base.RenderEndTag(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag(); // this will close div
    }
}
```

To connect this adapter to you application you have two options. First is to do it programmatically in page **constructor**:

```
var adapters = Context.Request.Browser.Adapters;
var customValidatorType = typeof(CustomValidator).AssemblyQualifiedName;
var adapterType = typeof(CustomValidatorAdapter).AssemblyQualifiedName;
if (!adapters.Contains(customValidatorType))
{
    adapters.Add(customValidatorType, adapterType);
}
```

Second option is to use `.browser` file:

Add new `Browser File` to your project. It will reside in `App_Browsers` folder. Then replace contents with following declaration:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
            <controlAdapters>
                <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator" 
                         adapterType="<your namespace>.CustomValidatorAdapter" />
            </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```